# How to translate "Do you miss him"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, verb

I would like to translate this simple sentence into German. Are the following translations correct?

1. Fehlt er Dir?
2. Vermisst er Dich?
3. Vermisst Du ihn?

Is there a different usage of *fehlen* or *vermissen*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 1st and the 3rd are correct.

The more literal translation would be

> Vermisst du ihn?

The 2nd is wrong. It would mean

> Does he miss you?

Both *[fehlen](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?input=vermissen&service=canooNet)*, and *[vermissen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fehlen)* are synonymously used in this context but note the change in grammatical case:

> Du <sup>*Nom.*</sup> fehlst mir <sup>*Dat.*</sup>.
>   Ich <sup>*Nom.*</sup> vermisse dich <sup>*Akk.*</sup>.